# Logic rule for implication

Tags: equations, logic

I need some help with making the rule for implication i Latex. My biggest problem is the box.

[image: Rule for implication]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A little starting code would be nice.

Comment: There are packages helping to typeset natural deduction proofs. See [LaTeX for Logicians|Natural deduction proofs](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/).

Comment: @gernot Though I don't know any which look like that. If this is from a textbook, it would help to know which one.

Comment: Well, these are the packages logicians in science use for their publications. Some time ago `proof.sty` was en vogue,  but it is a bit outdated now and no longer maintained, so people now prefer `busproofs.sty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example with `\boxed` of package `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \frac{
      \boxed{
        \begin{array}{c}
          \phi\\
          \vdots\\
          \psi
        \end{array}
      }
    }{
      \phi \rightarrow \psi
    }
    \rightarrow
    - \mathbf{I}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With a better middle line, removed additional horizontal margins of `array`,
and fine-tuned position of `\vdots`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Frac}[2]{%
  % Even numbered box and register numbers smaller than 10 are
  % for local assignments.
  \begingroup
    % "Numerator" in box 0
    \sbox0{$#1\m@th$}%
    % "Denominator" in box 2
    \sbox2{$#2\m@th$}%
    % Maximum width in \dimen2
    \ifdim\wd0 > \wd2 %
      \dimen0=\wd0 %
    \else
      \dimen0=\wd2 %
    \fi
    % Add overshoot (5pt) of the line
    \advance\dimen0 by 10pt\relax
    % Vertical separation
    \dimen2=3pt\relax
    \setbox4=\vbox{%
      \hbox to \dimen0{\hfill\unhcopy0\hfill}%
      \kern\dimen2
      \hrule % default line thickness: 0.4pt
      \kern\dimen2
      \hbox to \dimen0{\hfill\unhcopy2\hfill}%
      \kern0pt\relax
    }%
    % Box for measuring height of math axis
    \sbox0{$\vcenter{}$}%
    % Set result with the line at the math axis
    \raise\dimexpr\ht0 - \ht2 - \dp2 - \dimen2 - .2pt\relax\copy4 %
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
    \Frac{
      \boxed{
        \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
          \phi\\[-2pt]
          \vdots\\
          \psi
        \end{array}
      }
    }{
      \phi \rightarrow \psi
    }
    \rightarrow
    - \mathbf{I}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with better middle line]